# jquery validated form sends blank emails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, email

The form works fine, if you fill it, it sends the email and if you don't fill all the inputs, it warns you that you must do it and won't send the form  until you do it.

I'm using I'm using jquery.validate.js for this but lately, I've been getting Blank Emails. If the validate is working (I even tested in old browsers), why is it sending me blank emails?

HTML

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contacto.php">
                <fieldset>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" required> 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea class="input-xlarge" name="message" id="message" rows="3" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" class="demo-pricing demo-pricing-1">Submit</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="demo-pricing demo-pricing-1">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
$subject = "Web";

$to = 'contact@web.com';
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
$headers = "From: " . $_POST["name"]; 
$headers .= "<" . $_POST["email"] . ">\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . $_POST["email"]; 

$message .= "************************************************** \n";
$message .= "Contact \n";
$message .= "************************************************** \n\n";  

$message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST["name"] . "\r";
$message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST["email"] . "\r";
$message .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST["message"] . "\r";

$mail_sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>         <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">         window.alert('behold, we are aware of you')
    window.location.href='index.html';         </script>     <?php } else { ?>     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">         alert('nope, try again');      </script>     <?php     }
```

**update:** Turns out it was some issue with the server or so they told me, and there was nothing i could have done.

Comment: Ensure you use `\r\n` to terminate each line in `$message` as well.

Comment: Try adding `\r\n` after your `Return-path` line.

Comment: So what's the real problem here?  That your form is filled out but the email is empty?  Or that an empty form is emailed?  What basic troubleshooting have you done?  Have you looked at what's in the `$_POST` array?

Comment: An empty form is emailed, Sorry I it wasn't clear.
Also, I added \r\n to terminate each line as vee and jboneca suggested, in one of the forms (I've this problem with two different websites) and as far, it hasn't send blank emails again (at least over the weekend). I'll do the same with the other one to see if it works.
Thank you guys

Comment: i keep getting blank mails, i'm exasperated

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using a client side validation, doesn't assure that you will always receive valid inputs in the back-end. You should always do validation in your PHP script as well, irrespective of whether you do that in the browser. There may be cases when the user has JS disabled or even a maliciously framed request to your server side script.

Comment: How is this general advice a solution to his problem?

Comment: Because it is not mentioned in the question if the form sends a blank email every time the form is submitted. It could be a result of a very different scenario.

Comment: I agree, which is why I posted a _comment_, not an answer.

Comment: You are right! We'd need to confirm what's happening. Thanks for letting me know about it.